# Problema con Login en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sesiones, sharedpreferences, navigation-drawer

hice una app en Flutter, esta funciona correctamente, solo que tengo un problema, tengo un drawer donde si eres invitado aparece iniciar sesión o registrarte, cuando doy login, me manda a otra pantalla para hacer el inicio de sesión y mando por prefs las variables obtenidas, y después de eso regreso al menu, solo que al regresar por primera vez no me detecta los datos sino hasta que hago login por segunda ocasión ahi si cambia las variables, me podrían ayudar, les pongo el código del menu

```
  String? nombreUser = "";
  String? correoUser = "";
  String? id_user = "";
  int? login = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadPrefs();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      drawer:  login == null ? DrawerWidget("Hola", "Invitado", false) : DrawerWidget(nombreUser, correoUser, true),
...

//aqui es donde se supone tiene que obtener los prefs del login
Future _loadPrefs()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState((){
      nombreUser = prefs.getString('nombre');
      correoUser = prefs.getString('correo');
      id_user = prefs.getString('id');
      login = prefs.getInt('login');
    });

  }
```

En la del login tengo estas funciones:

```
Future <void> _login() async{
    if(_txtUsuario.text.isNotEmpty && _txtPass.text.isNotEmpty){
      try{
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (BuildContext c){
              return ProgressDialog(message: "Procesando la información...",);
            }
        );
        var u = _txtUsuario.text.trim();
        var p = _txtPass.text.trim();
        var url = Uri.parse("https:mi ws o api");
        final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
        var body = jsonEncode({
          "usuario": u,
          "pass": p,
          "type": "login"
        });
        var response = await http.post(url,headers: headers, body: body);
        var datos = jsonDecode(response.body);
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
          if(datos['status'] == true){
            Navigator.pop(context);
            var id = datos['result']['id'];
            var nombre = datos['result']['nombre'];
            var correo = datos['result']['correo'];

            //mandamos las variables
            dataShared(id, correo, nombre, 1);
            //cambiamos la navegacion
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => const MenuPage())); //AQUI REGRESA AL MENU
          }else{
            Navigator.pop(context);
            var msgError = datos['result']['error_msg'];
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(msgError)));
          }
        }else{
          Navigator.pop(context);
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Error del servidor")));
        }
      }on Exception catch (e){
        Navigator.pop(context);
        print(e);
      }
    }
    else{
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Los campos no pueden quedar vacios.")));
    }
  }


  Future<void> dataShared(id, correo, nombre, log) async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await prefs.setString('nombre', nombre);
    await prefs.setString('correo', correo);
    await prefs.setInt('login', 1);
    await prefs.setString('id', id);
  }
```

Como les comento si inicia sesión pero hasta la segunda vez y pues debería ser a la primera vez,

Gracias!

Comment: Cuando naveges a la pantalla de login, haz un await del navigator. De esa forma, la función que llame a Navigator, se quedará esperando que termine el proceso de la nueva pantalla. Después del navigator puedes volver a llamar al método para comprobar si el usuario está logeado.

Comment: gracias, me podrías ayudar diciéndome como seria mas o menos??